# Codename One - Upload big files 15M+

Tags: file-upload, codenameone

We are trying to upload videos taken using the app to a remote server.

Currently we are zipping the video file and adding the byte array to a ConnectionRequest.

The zipping fishiness successful and the request is started but then it just disappears. It never reached our server.

Can anyone please help. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Videos are already compressed so zip won't provide any benefit in size. Developers upload files larger than 100mb using multipart request so this shouldn't be a problem.

I would use the addData method that accepts a reference to the file.

Historically, I had issues with this because the server placed an attachment size limit on the files.